# how Fingerprints are converting into binary?

Tags: binary, fingerprint, converters

I am searching about the conversion that how fingerprints directly converts into binary. I searched a lot about this matter but didn't get the satisfactory answer. I read some articles about it but on those articles there is just a concept of validation that how someone gain access. but i want to know how fingerprints coverts to binary?
Here are the articles i read
[fingerprint scanner](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/fingerprint-scanner.htm)
[Finger print binary code](https://nikuv.wordpress.com/tag/fingerprint-binary-code/)

Comment: There’s no single way to do it. It depends on the device, library, etc.

Comment: is there any algorithm or something else that convert it into binary form?? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: As I said, there are several. It all depends on the system you’re using. If you want to do such a system yourself then I assume there’s some research papers on the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although there is not a single way as they mentioned above..check it out hope you get some thing useful

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Block-Diagram-of-Fingerprint-Minutiae-Points-Feature-Extraction-Algorithm-Step-3-Image_fig1_260602525

Comment: Yes these are helpful links

Comment: satisfied to help you